# Does OpsCenter Community work with a single-node Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 64 bits with OpenJDK 1.8.0_66. Cassandra 3.3 and OpsCenter 5.2.4 are installed from apt packages and running locally. I am using the following sources.

```
deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 33x main
deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main
```

The OpsCenter doc says: "In Add Cluster, enter the Hostnames or IP addresses of two or three nodes in the cluster, set the JMX and Native Transport ports, and click Save Cluster".

I have a single-node cluster, so I don't have two or three IP addresses to enter. When I enter the address of the node, I get the following message: "Error creating cluster: Unable to connect to cluster. Error is: Unable to connect to any seed nodes, tried ['127.0.0.1']".

I am using the default ports. `netstat -an` gives among others the following lines.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          :::*                    LISTEN
```

`nodetool status` is working fine.

```
$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  201.17 KB  256          ?       04da2c59-1a88-4ed3-9af9-8f64ae27e9ac  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

So is `cqlsh`.

```
$ cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.3 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

After looking at other questions I tried uncommenting the following in /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh. I tried both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. It did not help.

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<hostname>"
```

There is nothing in /var/log/cassandra/debug.log or /var/log/cassandra/system.log when the connection attempts fail. The only log messages are from Cassandra starting/stopping.

Is it possible at all to use OpsCenter with a single-node cluster? If so, what might I be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cassandra 3.3 and OpsCenter 5.2.4

You're out of luck, **OpsCenter 5.x** only work for Cassandra 2.1 branch and the future OpsCenter 6.x that will be compatible with Cassandra 3.x branch will only be available wit the Datastax Enterprise version, read this: http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/opscPolicyChanges.html